# How to "track" missing ctor initialisation list arguments?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I'm sure there is ugly thing everyone time to time faces with.

The problem is adding one more field to a class and forgetting expand initialisation list e.g.:

```
class T{
  private:
    field1;
    ...
    field10;
};

T::T( int speedValue ):
field1( Speed::MphToMps(speedValue) ),
field2( new OtherClass(14,5,15) ),
field3( PublicValueGenerator::generateNewFieldValue(0,15) ),
...,
field10( "unpredictable value" );
```

And if in hurry I add some field, say newForgottenField, time to time I forget to set init value.
As I remeber some IDEs can give a hint, but vim+addons is my choice :)

So mb there is some hint for simplifying tracking such situations or some rule of thumb or rude macros which gives warning or compile-time error(that would be amazing:))?
How do you overcome that obstacle?

Best regards

Comment: Is the "god class delusion", eh?

Comment: How do you want to "track" them? By a compiler warning/error? By vim itself? Through an external analysis program?

Comment: If it's an error you make often, add it to you checklist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using g++ then it provides an option which enables warnings for constructs that violate guidelines in Scott Meyer's Effective C++ :)
The option is:

```
-Weffc++
```

Do note that it will also enable a number of other warnings as well.Also, not all of the standard library headers follow Meyers guildelines.

Comment: That's killer-feature! Seems, that is exactly what I dreamed of. Never heard of it before...

Answer (score 1):

One way to obtain what you want is to ensure that all of your fields are instances of classes that either have a default constructor that does what is needed or only have constructors that require arguments.

This is not always convenient, but it would certainly solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question and would be useful to be able to check easily, but in general the solutions C++ can actually support have a combination of error-proneness, verbosity, and obfuscation that makes them more onorous than the problem you're trying to solve.  Still - for the sake of discussion - here's a few approaches to this...

You can create a class that doesn't have a default constructor:

```
template <typename T>
class Explicitly_Initialised
{
  public:
    Explicitly_Initialised(const T& t) : t_(t) { }
    T& operator T() { return t_; }
    const T& operator T() const { return t_; }
  private:
    T t_;
};
```

Or, you could have a class that throws if the object is read from before being given a value (perhaps only in "debug" builds if you have such a concept).  You could decide whether a value from `operator=` was ok.  You'd need a `bool has_been_initialised_;` member to track this, set to false in the default constructor.  One hassle would be that `operator T()` wouldn't know whether the variable was about to be read before being written, so to do a thorough job you may need a proxy object to manage that situation: painful.

Alternatively, and too messy to actually recommended - you could probably hack together a class that accepted a type list, had a member object for each of those types, and insisted on a matching list in the constructor; it would be difficult allow that generic class to accept normal arbitrary identifiers for accessing the data members (it's easy to allow numeric access, or even type-based access if the types were unique) (you could probably get it working with macro hackery).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this in C++11 is to provide element initializers for all primitive members:

```
class T {
private:
    int field1{};
    ...
    int field10{};
};
```